# Want my script to work on the original image instead of the resized image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Question I need someone to answer**
What do I need to change for the below script to work on the original image instead of the resized image?

**Info to help solve my problem**
The images come from a scanner and contain 2 or 3 receipes written or typed onto 3"x5" index cards.

The script correctly identifies each receipe and saves them to individual files. Unfortunately, the text in the new images is to small for my OCR script to accurately read the hand writen receipes.

Removal of the `img = cv2.resize()` line (line 54) results in "IndexError: list index out of range" being thrown by `def transform()` on line 33.

```
# Original Script: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-detect-an-object-from-static-image-and-crop-it-from-the-image-using-openCV

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def transform(pos):
    # This function is used to find the corners of the object and the dimensions of the object

    pts=[]
    n=len(pos)

    for i in range(n):
        pts.append(list(pos[i][0]))

    sums={}
    diffs={}
    tl=tr=bl=br=0

    for i in pts:
        x=i[0]
        y=i[1]
        sum=x+y
        diff=y-x
        sums[sum]=i
        diffs[diff]=i

    sums=sorted(sums.items())
    diffs=sorted(diffs.items())
    n=len(sums)

    # The IndexError occurs on this line
    rect=[sums[0][1],diffs[0][1],diffs[n-1][1],sums[n-1][1]]
    #       top-left   top-right   bottom-left   bottom-right

    h1 = np.sqrt((rect[0][0]-rect[2][0])**2 + (rect[0][1]-rect[2][1])**2)        #height of left side
    h2 = np.sqrt((rect[1][0]-rect[3][0])**2 + (rect[1][1]-rect[3][1])**2)        #height of right side
    h = max(h1, h2)

    w1 = np.sqrt((rect[0][0]-rect[1][0])**2 + (rect[0][1]-rect[1][1])**2)        #width of upper side
    w2 = np.sqrt((rect[2][0]-rect[3][0])**2 + (rect[2][1]-rect[3][1])**2)        #width of lower side
    w = max(w1, w2)

    return int(w), int(h), rect

img = cv2.imread('source_image.png')

#
# Resizing of image is done here
#
# Removal of these lines results in "IndexError: list index out of range" being displayed
r = 500.0 / img.shape[1]
dim = (500, int(img.shape[0] * r))
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)
edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edge.copy(), 1, 1)

# Give each output image a unique name
loopcnt = 0
for pos in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(pos, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(pos, 0.02 * peri, True)

    w, h, arr = transform(approx)

    if w > 0 and h > 0:

        pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w, 0], [0, h], [w, h]])
        pts1 = np.float32(arr)
        M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (w, h))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite("output_image_"+str(loopcnt)+".png", image)

        loopcnt+=1
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem! For future reference, note that questions like these work better if you post a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. Just creating that example often leads you to find the problem by yourself. And it makes it a lot less work for the community to point out the problem (I would never try to read the big block of code that you posted). And it shows the community that you have worked on the problem on your own for a while before giving up, which makes us more likely to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

The script works on one image at a time. If you have multiple images to process, you will need to call this script once per image.

```
# Original Script: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-detect-an-object-from-static-image-and-crop-it-from-the-image-using-openCV

##########
# Process a scanned image and place each receipe card into its own image file.
#
# WARNING: This script will overwrite existing files when saving output images.
#
# Created: 2017-12-29 1148
# Modified: 2017-12-31 1358
##########

import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import argparse
import os

def transform(pos):
    # This function is used to find the corners and dimensions of the object

    pts=[]
    n=len(pos)

    for i in range(n):
        pts.append(list(pos[i][0]))

    sums={}
    diffs={}
    tl=tr=bl=br=0

    for i in pts:
        x=i[0]
        y=i[1]
        sum=x+y
        diff=y-x
        sums[sum]=i
        diffs[diff]=i

    sums=sorted(sums.items())
    diffs=sorted(diffs.items())
    n=len(sums)

    rect=[sums[0][1],diffs[0][1],diffs[n-1][1],sums[n-1][1]]
    #       top-left   top-right   bottom-left   bottom-right

    h1 = np.sqrt((rect[0][0]-rect[2][0])**2 + (rect[0][1]-rect[2][1])**2)        #height of left side
    h2 = np.sqrt((rect[1][0]-rect[3][0])**2 + (rect[1][1]-rect[3][1])**2)        #height of right side
    h = max(h1, h2)

    w1 = np.sqrt((rect[0][0]-rect[1][0])**2 + (rect[0][1]-rect[1][1])**2)        #width of upper side
    w2 = np.sqrt((rect[2][0]-rect[3][0])**2 + (rect[2][1]-rect[3][1])**2)        #width of lower side
    w = max(w1, w2)

    return int(w), int(h), rect

def file_choices(fname):

    # List of valid file extensions
    choices = ('bmp', 'dib' ,'jpeg' ,'jpg' ,'jpe' ,'jp2' ,'png' ,'webp' ,'pbm' ,'pgm' ,'ppm' ,'sr' ,'ras' ,'tiff' ,'tif')

    # Get file extension
    ext = os.path.splitext(fname)[1][1:]

    # Check if extension is valid
    if ext not in choices:
       ap.error("File doesn't end with one of {}".format(choices))

    return fname

##
## Main program starts here
##

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="Path to source image", type=lambda s:file_choices(s))
ap.add_argument("-c", "--color", help="If set, output images will be in color if original image is in color. Default is to return grayscale (black & white) images.", action="store_true")
args = ap.parse_args()

srcimage = args.image

# Save output images in same directory as srcimage
destpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(srcimage))

# -Should the output images be in color or grayscale?
# -Note: If the source image is alread in grayscale, this setting
#        will have no effect on the output images.
if args.color:
    returncolor = True
else:
    returncolor = False

# Load in the source image
imgorig = cv2.imread(srcimage)

# Resizing of image is done here to speed up processing
ratio = 500.0 / imgorig.shape[1]
dim = (500, int(imgorig.shape[0] * ratio))
img = cv2.resize(imgorig, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Add a blur to remove some of the noise
# Image noise is random variation of brightness or color.
# More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)

# Find the contours of the receipe cards
edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edge.copy(), 1, 1)

# Give each output image a unique name
loopcnt = 0

# Process all found contours
for pos in contours:

    # Get length of the contour in pixels
    # peri is a float
    peri = cv2.arcLength(pos, True)

    # Approximates a polygonal curve(s) with the specified precision
    # More info: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(pos, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # Find the corners and dimensions of the object
    w, h, arr = transform(approx)

    # Only process contours that have a valid dimension
    if w > 0 and h > 0:

        # Adjust width and height to match dimensions of
        # each receipe card on the original image
        wr = int(w / ratio)
        hr = int(h / ratio)

        # Adjust pixel coordinates to match orignal image
        arr_us=[]
        for a in arr:
            a[0] = int(math.floor(a[0] / ratio))
            a[1] = int(math.floor(a[1] / ratio))
            arr_us.append(list(a))

        arr = arr_us

        # Convert all of the numbers to floats
        pts1 = np.float32(arr)
        pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [wr, 0], [0, hr], [wr, hr]])

        # Changes perspective to a top-down view (a.k.a.: birds eye view)
        M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        dst = cv2.warpPerspective(imgorig, M, (wr, hr))

        if returncolor:
            # Keep original image colors in output images
            image = dst
        else:
            # Convert output images to grayscale before saving
            image = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Save each receipe card to individual image files
        # WARNING: This will overwrite existing files.
        cv2.imwrite(destpath + "/output_"+str(loopcnt)+".png", image)

    loopcnt+=1
```